# assignment operator vs assign() function in strings C++

Tags: c++, string

I am using strings in C++. Let's say I have a stringA and I want it to assign the value of stringB.

```
1st way:
stringA = stringB

2nd way:
stringA.assign(stringB);
```

Can anyone please tell which is faster and good method ?

Comment: The two options you have shown have the same effect.   Neither is likely to be faster or "more good" by most reasonable measures.

Comment: Okay , thanks for the help.

Comment: These ways should have same performance, though the one with simple `=` looks more general and less obscure.